# Using a regex in laravel instead of chaining orWhere statements

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using eloquent to write a query to my db.  I am chaining several orWhere statements and I am thinking there must be a regex way.  I am trying to return all skill fields that do not start with alphanumeric.
Here is what I have so far

```
$skills = $skills->where('skill', 'LIKE', " %")->orWhere('skill', 'LIKE', ",%")->orWhere('skill', 'LIKE', "-%")
                ->orWhere('skill', 'LIKE', ":%");
```

Instead of writing out every possible non alphanumeric character chaining a orWhere how else would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use whereRaw. Something like this should get you started:

```
$skills->whereRaw("skill REGEXP '^[^0-9a-zA-Z]'");
```